# How do I change the database file location for couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

I've got couchdb installed from a package manager (Ubuntu, 10.04), but the partition where couchdb is installed is not especially big (~5GB). I'd like to move the database files to a bigger partition I set aside for the db, but I can't seem to find how to do it anywhere.

I suspect it's a local.ini tweak, but I've got nothing to back that up.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That is in local.ini

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = /path/to/the/databases
view_index_dir = /path/to/the/views
```

Good luck!

Comment: Just what I'm looking for. Thanks! Is there a comprehensive doc with these somewhere I overlooked?

Comment: I suppose a charitable answer is, the .ini files are self-documenting.

Comment: *Smack forehead* Turns out I looked everywhere but the default.ini file. Awesome.

Comment: this is an old question, I know, but did that really work for you? i can't get couchdb to write to my specified directories-- it still insists on writing to /var/lib no matter what the local.ini says...

Comment: Hi, Harlo. CouchDB can read *multiple* config files in a series, each one overriding the config of the one before (sort of like CSS). So make sure you are editing the *final* file in that sequence (by default, `local.ini`.) Also, you can try using the `/_config/` API. If you have more problems, create a Server Fault question and we'll figure it out there.

Comment: if you are moving items / linking items, you have to create the .databasename_view directory with the proper owner / group first, or the view wont generate.  Couchdb 1.6.1

Comment: is it `default.ini` or `local.ini`?

Answer (score 7):

You could also take advantage of symbolic linking.  Move the contents of /var/lib/couchdb into your desired directory, and create a symbolic link.  Be sure to give the couchdb user permissions to the symlink.

Comment: Agreed.  Symbolic linking is the least intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for Couchdb 3.2.2:

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/config/intro.html

Here is what worked for me in Ubuntu:

1. Stop the couchdb service

   sudo service couchdb stop
2. Modify the default.ini file

   sudo vi /opt/couchdb/etc/default.ini

Lines to modify:

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = {new location}
view_index_dir = {new location}
```

3. Copy the data

sudo rsync -av /opt/couchdb/data/ {new location}

4. Restart and check the service

   sudo service couchdb start

   sudo service couchdb status